# Laratrust roles and permisions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

That's the way I found to create users as administrator and lower levels of roles. I know that there is a better and more clever way. Could anyone help me?

```
public function create()
    {
        if (Laratrust::hasRole('administrator')) {
            $roles = Role::where('id','>', 1)->get();
            return view('layouts.usuarios.create')->withRoles($roles);
        } else {
            $roles = Role::all();
            return view('layouts.usuarios.create')->withRoles($roles);
        }
    }
```

The role loop doesn't show the superadministrator one. How can I make this more efficient and dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show the superadministror?

Comment: Yes Erik, that's it.